# Is it ok to say "a distracting person / thing" & "a distracted person"?

Tags: word-usage

ok,

> to distract: to prevent (someone) from giving full attention to
>   something.[Source](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define:distract)

So, can I say "*I was distracted by a distracting sexy girl*", "*I was distracted by a distracting car*", & "*I am a distracted person  because I suffered attention disorder*"

so, Is it ok to say "*a distracting person / thing*" & "*a distracted person*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these are both OK, classic adjectival uses of participles. If something distracts you it is *distracting* and you are *distracted*.